# Scaling a math function from a specific vertex

Tags: image, mathematics

I have a model developed through a math function as shown below in the figure. I would like to scale the figure as shown in the figure without changing the vertex position.

Explanation of the figure:
The model seen is according to the function implemented. Now, the two vertices on the Y-axis remain where they are originally present and the surface of the model needs to be scaled proportionally in x,y (that is if scale factor of 2 along x, then the same scale factor 2 along y from the vertex) shown in red.

[image: Figure explaning the scaling modifications]

My guess is that the positioning of the origin needs to be changed but not sure how?

Any hacks to do address this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the best way to scale that with Blender would be, but I'd look at just adjusting your equation. Here's your $y$ equation:

$$y=\begin{cases}
0.5 & \text{if } u < 0 \\
\frac{u^2}{u^2+(1-u)^2}+0.5 & \text{if } 0 \leq u \leq 1\\
1.5 & \text{if } u > 1
\end{cases}$$

Notice that the main part of the middle equation, $\frac{u^2}{u^2+(1-u)^2}$, normally has a range of $[0,1]$ on the interval $[0,1]$. You are offsetting it by $0.5$. If we scale it, and change the offset of the third piece, we can place it wherever. Use this equation instead:

$$y=\begin{cases}
0.5 & \text{if } u < 0 \\
k \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{u}{k}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{u}{k}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{u}{k}\right)^2}+0.5 & \text{if } 0 \leq \frac{u}{k} \leq 1\\
k + 0.5 & \text{if } \frac{u}{k} > 1
\end{cases}$$

where $k$ is your scalar. You can try it online using Desmos [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ba7g3qpclp). (Thanks to [Rich Sedman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29586/rich-sedman) for help with scaling horizontally).

In a Python expression, it would be this (substituting in whatever value for `k`):

```
(0.5 if u<0 else (k*((u/k)**2/((u/k)**2+(1-(u/k))**2)+0.5) if (u/k)<=1 else k+0.5))*v
```

Comment: Nice answer. With a few tweaks to ‘x’ you can include scaling horizontally - see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ba7g3qpclp

Comment: @RichSedman Heh. I totally missed that second part of the scaling. I'll add that, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to have "u Step>1024" for math function? I am planning to have a geometry as above but with 2 models (named 'A', 'B') where A is a mirror of B and both are connected to the 0.5 line. If I have a combined model as one geometry, I must compromise on precision as I cant have 'u step'>1024. If A and B are modelled independently each geometry can have 1024 'u step' and have a better precision for the geometry. So, is it possible to export A, B as individual stl images with u steps = 1024 and merge them to get the desired output?